# Which design better when use foreign key instead of a string to store a list of id

Tags: database, database-design, data-structures

I'm building online examination system. I have designed to table, `Question` and `GeneralExam`. The table `GeneralExam` contains info about the exam like name, description, duration,...

Now I would like to design table `GeneralQuestion`, it will contain the ids of questions belongs to a general exam.

Currently, I have two ideas to design GeneralQuestion table:

1. It will have two columns: general_exam_id, question_id.
2. It will have two columns: general_exam_id,
   list_question_ids (string/text).

I would like to know which designing is better, or pros and cons of each designing.

I'm using Postgresql database.

Comment: Your question title is about performance, but you ask which design is better. This is a common misconception - you think better performance = better design. Actually, you should first focus on a well structured, maintainable design and ask the performance question only when you face real performance problems.

Comment: Please don't post the same question on multiple stack exchanges. Cross posting is not encouraged here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415511/how-different-performance-when-use-foreign-key-instead-of-a-string-to-store-a-li

Comment: @DocBrown sorry, i just think, with 1 general exam with 100 questions, first solution need 100 rows, second solution need only one row, so i just thought second solution can get id of question faster, so i thought that performance, i will edit my title.

Comment: @Oded sorry sir, i just want to have a quick answer :(

Comment: @KienThanh: do you really expect "100" rows to cause performance problems? If you would have said "100 million rows", that would be more understandable. And if you need to query for the questions of one exam, one SQL select will be enough in both cases.

Comment: @DocBrown I'm just example for easy understand. I just think when it grow up, and compare between 1 row and 100 rows, it's x100 times. Anyway, I'm still a student and have not much experience yet, I just collect experiences for doing better :)

Comment: The second one is a violation of first normal form.

Comment: Virtually any time you want to store a string of values in one field, you have made a mistake. One of the very first rules of database design is to NEVER put more than one piece of information in a field. Fields with concatenated information are MUCH harder to query and tend to perform poorly due to the queries being unable to use an index.

Comment: I don't think your schema is valid. What if a question would appear in more than 1 exam? What if an exam has versions? Have a look at: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20211/designing-server-side-database-to-store-user-specific-data

Comment: @EmmadKareem Thanks for pointing, I designed follow #1 solution, but then #2 solution came in my mind. Actually, I thought the #1 solution is good and followed it, but I just wonder how it different with #2 solution.

Comment: # 2 is wrong at least because it violates normal forms. #1 is wrong because questions may appear in different exam versions, which could inevitably arise in the future (at least in most such cases). See the link I have provided.

Comment: @EmmadKareem Maybe I should explain more about my project. In my project, General Exam have a collect random questions got form question table. Then, I will create exams for students, every exam will get same number of questions (which user defined when create general exam) from list questions of general exam, but they are randomize.

Answer (score 5):

The first design is the better one.

This is because you can then also create foreign keys to the questions. Also you have no further processing for parsing the list of ids. Also in this case you have the ability to get all questions together with the general exam query (only one round-trip to the database).

In the case of the second design you have to get the database entry for a general exam, parse the text and then query the database again for the questions...

Comment: The last point about extra queries to the DB was the deal breaker for me.

Answer (score 3):

- **Nice and Tricky Question**

It depends on usage. But most of the times INT key is preferred. Usually you will find something like ID to show the primary key.

Ultimately it depends on the usage. What kind of requirements you are going to have. Accordingly decide. But INT is most preferred.
Here I have explained both

**For int IDs (First option) #**

Identity field should be numeric and not string based, because

- Space saving (An int is 4 bytes, a string can be as many bytes as you like. Because of that, an int will always perform better)
- Performance reasons (matching keys on strings is slower than matching
  on integers)
- Data redundancy will be solved by int column. As Foreign keys need to
  be updated (and/or deleted) whenever the data is updated.
- Updates/deletes on a foreign key can be set to cascade.

**For String/Text (Second option) #**

- Using a foreign key means that to get user-readable data (ie, the
  text) a JOIN must be made. Using a descriptive foreign key, no JOIN
  needs to be made to get user-readable data. This includes reading
  with SELECTs and when INSERTing or modifying data. For example, to
  insert into AddressNum the groupId is needed.
- Human-readable data in the database. This will make it easier for the
  DBA to debug data issues, as they can use a SHOW CREATE TABLE to find
  the foreign key references, and then get a sample of data from one
  table and understand the scenario, without having to JOIN.

**I like the @user1598390's comment**

> OP is not asking whether to use int IDs or String IDs. He/she is
>   asking whether to used int IDs (one to many) or having all questions
>   IDs concatenated in a text column like "123311;121322;123455;123487".

First option I took as int IDs and Second option I took as Text/String.

It depends on usage. What kind of requirements you are going to have. Accordingly decide. Most of time, First option is preferred. In this case, for first option you have no further processing for parsing the list of ids.

Comment: thanks for exlain, i think i should be do first solution but i don't know why i should, now i'm know :)

Comment: Most welcome. Glad as this answer helped you. Also thanks for your nice and tricky question. :)

Comment: @MahbuburRAaman: perhaps I misunderstood you, but the "foreign key cascades" work only correctly when DB foreign keys are used. If I got the OP right, the String/Text suggestion is about having a list of IDs encoded in one string - this is a solution avoiding DB relations, so foreign keys and indexing won't work.

Comment: @DocBrown, You are right. But as a whole and explaining as pros/cons i would like to refer the point.

Comment: @MahbuburRAaman: Yes, but it is a "pro" point for int IDs, not for String/Text, so maybe just an accidental mistake.

Comment: @DocBrown, I respect you for your comment and presentation of your comment. It is my mistake. I am really Sorry. I have edited my answer. Today I have learned a big lesson from you. Thanks to You and Thanks to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: OP is not asking whether to use int IDs or String IDs. He/she is asking whether to used int IDs  (one to many) or having all questions IDs concatenated in a text column like "123311;121322;123455;123487".

Comment: @user1598390, Thanks for a good comment. I have edited my answer to reflect your comment.